# Add signature at the end of the document

Tags: docusignapi

In my app, the user uploads the agreement doc and takes signature on them. The document uploaded is different for every user. I can't be sure that it will contain a specific anchor text. How can I take the sign at the bottom of the doc?

Docusign documentation suggests adding white anchor text at the end of the doc. Is there a way I can add formatted(white font colour) text to the file stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one option is to use X/Y coordinates for position. You may first need to make a call to retrieve all the documents and find out how many pages and then find the size of the page and calculate where to position your tag.

If it were me - I'll add a blank one page document to the envelope and put the signing element in that new document that only has 1 empty page and your signature. That guarantees it's at the end without the need to calculate number of pages or position etc.